# How to solve differential equations in for loop in mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, scripting

I have a system of differential equation for which I want analytical solution. Let say my equations are -

```
x'[t] - X[[i]]*y[t] == 0, 
y'[t] + X[[i]]*x[t] == 0
```

where `X = [0.11, 0.21, 0.31, 0.41]`

How can I write a for loop such that it takes `X[[i]]` from `X` and find the analytical solution and print/plot it?

I am trying following -

```
For[i = 1, i < 5,
    sols = DSolve[{x'[t] - X[[i]]*y[t] == 0,
                   y'[t] + X[[i]]*x[t] == 0}, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0, {x, y}, t]
   ];
```

Unfortunately, it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

```
c = Range[11, 41, 10]/100;
sol = Table[
   DSolveValue[{x'[t] - c[[i]]*y[t] == 0, y'[t] + c[[i]]*x[t] == 0, 
     x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, t], {i, Length@c}];
Plot[sol, {t, 0, 60}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Okkes Dulgerci. Could you please tell how to export solutions x[t] and y[t] separately in different files.

Comment: `x[t]=sol[[All,1]]`  and `y[t]=sol[[All,2]]`

Comment: Or `{x[t],y[t]}=Transpose@sol`

Answer (score 1):

```
coefs = {0.11, 0.21, 0.31, 0.41}
DSolve[{x'[t] - #*y[t] == 0, y'[t] + #*x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, 
    y[0] == 0}, {x, y}, t] & /@ coefs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
X = {0.11, 0.21, 0.31, 0.41} 
sols = {};
For[i = 1, i < 5, i++, 
AppendTo[sols,DSolve[{x'[t] - X[[i]]*y[t] == 0, y'[t] + X[[i]]*x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]]];
```